# Chart that pull data from an open workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Could you kindly help check this code? The code is not working as the chart is not coming up. I am trying to plot a chart that extract data from another open workbook. Thanks.

```
Sub Macro2()
'
 'Declarations
    Dim fileName As Variant
    Dim myFilePath As String
    Dim Wkbk As Variant


    myFilePath = "C:\Users\Wonggba\Desktop\y\"
    fileName = Dir(myFilePath)

    While fileName <> ""

        Debug.Print fileName

        Set Wkbk = Workbooks.Open(myFilePath & fileName)      'Open Workbook

        ThisWorkbook.ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = fileName
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=[fileName]NPVExcelSheet1!$AY$4:$AY$45" 'The chart should use the data from the open Wkbk
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "[fileName]NPVExcelSheet1!$AX$4:$AX$45"   'The chart should use the data from the open Wkbk

        Wkbk.Close SaveChanges:=True  'Close file and save changes

        fileName = Dir 'Set the fileName to the next file

    Wend


End Sub
```

Comment: fully wrap code in tgs

Comment: Am sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: At what point do you ask the chart "to come up"? Why do you want it to come up?

Answer (score 0):

The following two lines will cause errors:

```
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=[fileName]NPVExcelSheet1!$AY$4:$AY$45" 'The chart should use the data from the open Wkbk
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "[fileName]NPVExcelSheet1!$AX$4:$AX$45"   'The chart should use the data from the open Wkbk
```

Instead, they should read:

```
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=[" & filename & "]NPVExcelSheet1!$AY$4:$AY$45" 'The chart should use the data from the open Wkbk
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "[" & filename & "]NPVExcelSheet1!$AX$4:$AX$45"   'The chart should use the data from the open Wkbk
```

In your original code, you were putting the literal "filename" in the Chart values, not the value of the variable `filename`. The modified code concatenates the value of `filename` into the input string.

Comment: Thank you. But it seems the chart is only plotting one excel workbook data and not the others. Or the plot for each loop is being removed on the chart before the next loop. What I want to do is to plot the data for each loop in the same chart together.

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the filename variable into the string for the series source. I have added a series of other observations as well regarding potential changes to code.

In order to avoid overwriting the existing series 1. You need to reference the newly added series during the loop.

```
Option Explicit '<==Checks for declarations, spellings, type consistency
Public Sub PlotGraph() '<== Useful descriptive name
    Dim fileName As String '<== Correct type declarations
    Dim myFilePath As String
    Dim Wkbk As Workbook
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim myChart As Chart '<== Use a variable to reference your chart object
    Set myChart = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(1).Chart '<<Change as appropriate

    myFilePath = "C:\Users\Wonggba\Desktop\y\"
    fileName = Dir(myFilePath)

    While fileName <> vbNullString '<== vbNullString is faster for comparisons
        Debug.Print fileName
        Set Wkbk = Workbooks.Open(myFilePath & fileName) 'Open Workbook

        With myChart '<== Use a With statement to work with parent object and reduce code repetition
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries '<== SeriesCollection is more robust
             counter = counter + 1
            .SeriesCollection(counter).Name = fileName
            .SeriesCollection(counter).Values = "[" & fileName & "]NPVExcelSheet1!$AX$4:$AX$45" 'The chart should use the data from the open Wkbk
            .SeriesCollection(counter).XValues = "[" & fileName & "]NPVExcelSheet1!$AY$4:$AY$45" 'The chart should use the data from the open Wkbk
        End With

        Wkbk.Close
        fileName = Dir                           'Set the fileName to the next file
    Wend
End Sub
```

You may want to set the x-axis outside of the loop and then simply add new series to the existing chart.

Comment: You are new to SO but it is considered good etiquette to respond to each person who bothers to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: No worries. Welcome to SO  :-)

Comment: Thank you for taking time out to help with the code. Most grateful.